# Do a local IP redirection with Virtualmin/Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, ip

I have two servers running Debian with Virtualmin/Webmin and I wanted to look how can I redirect a subdomain, like a.example.com to my second server. In example:

- I have a.example.com on the first server, IP address 192.168.1.20
- I have a second server with IP address 192.168.1.21
- My router is set to redirect connections to 80 port the first server IP (192.168.1.20), but when accessing a.example.com how can I do so Apache redirects it to the second server (192.168.1.21)?
  Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should use `mod_proxy` for this case.

Set up one Apache at the front, and use `mod_proxy` to fetch the content from one of the the two servers behind.

Comment: Then I would do something like:                             <Location />
                ProxyPass 192.168.1.21
</Location>

Comment: EDIT: exactly, thats the way i would do it

Comment: Yep I know, but then I should add entries to the main server's hosts file so second server can recognize it. EDIT: thinking about it I think maybe not, but not sure as I don't have the server her right now, will mark as answer